# how reverse query ManytoMany Django

Tags: django, reverse, m2m

I have these two models and I want to display the project with a specific task in my page. These are my models:

```
class Project (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Project name", max_length=25)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, verbose_name="tasksInProject", blank=True,
                                   related_name="projects+")

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Task", max_length=50)
```

I call this view:

```
class TaskToProjectFilterView(DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name = "vivs/task_filter.html"
    context_object_name = "task_filter"
```

And this is my html template:

```
<h4>filter : {{ task_filter }} </h4>
<h4>projects : 
{% for element in task_filter.projects.all %}
    {{ element }} 
{% endfor %}
</h4>
```

This code displays the `{{ task_filter }}` but not the list of `{{ task_filter.projects.all }}`.

Can you help me? I don't understand my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the `'+'` in `'projects+'` in the `related_name` is  a typo, otherwise it would totally explain why `task_filter.projects.all` does not work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer ! It work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) stated, remove the `+` sign and it should work as expected, using:

```
{% for element in task_filter.projects.all %}
```

From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+' or end it with '+'. For example, this will ensure that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model:

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, thanks for the explanation!